# scp to a remote server using pexpect

Tags: python, scp, pexpect

I'm trying to learn a little bit on pexpect: in particular I'm trying to copy a file from my laptop to a remote server.
I'm experiencing a weird behaviour: more or less the same code works if I write it line by line but it won't if I run it as a script.
Here is what I write line-by-line:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('scp pathdir/file.ext username@hostname:pathdir')
r=child.expect ('assword:')
r
```

it returns 0 and I finish the job with the password

```
child.sendline ('password')
```

When I do ssh to the server I found my file there. So I collect all the steps in a script; it exits without errors, but the file it was not copied... why? But more importantly, how can I fix that?

Here is the script:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('scp pathdir/file.ext username@hostname:pathdir')
r=child.expect ('assword:')
print r
if r==0:
    child.sendline ('password')
child.close()
```

I'm not sure how pexpect works so I print r to be sure it is 0. And it is.

Comment: do you start the script from the folder where `file.ext` is ?

Comment: Yes: the script and file.ext are in the same directory. However the question needs an edit: file.ext is given with its full path.

Comment: run into the same problem. Have you solved it now?

Comment: No. Do not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the "same" problem recently. Here's how I did it. I hope this will definitely help you.

Your question : 
`I'm not sure how pexpect works so I print r to be sure it is 0. And it is.`

Yes it is zero.

Try the code below :

```
    try:
        var_password  = "<YOUR PASSWORD>" Give your password here
        var_command = "scp pathdir/file.ext username@hostname:pathdir"
        #make sure in the above command that username and hostname are according to your server
        var_child = pexpect.spawn(var_command)
        i = var_child.expect(["password:", pexpect.EOF])

        if i==0: # send password                
                var_child.sendline(var_password)
                var_child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
        elif i==1: 
                print "Got the key or connection timeout"
                pass

    except Exception as e:
        print "Oops Something went wrong buddy"
        print e
```

child.expect can accept more than one arguments. In such case you have to send those arguments in form of list. In above scenario, if output of pexpect.spawn is "password:" then `i` will get 0 as output and if `EOF` is encountered instead of "password" then the value of `i` will be 1.

I hope this would clear your doubt. If not, then let me know. I will try to enhance the explanation for you.

Answer (score 1):

After sending password i.e

```
child.sendline('password')
```

write:

```
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

This waits till copying of file finishes

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It happened when I specified the home directory (~/) of the client as the destination. This worked fine when manually typing in the scp command but for some reason not when using pexpect. Simply using a relative or absolute destination directory path solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

you have to finish your code with `child.interact()` then it will run the whole commands that you have written before that.

It will look like this:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('scp pathdir/file.ext username@hostname:pathdir')
r=child.expect ('assword:')
print r
if r==0:
    child.sendline ('password')
child.interact()
child.close()
```